# C#, Windows Phone 8 install directory

Tags: c#, windows-phone

How add files to install directory in C# WindowsPhone8 SDK?

I'm trying to read text file, which is in Content directory of my project. The problem is, that there is no Importer for text. But it doesn't matter. The real problem is, that I don't know how to add file to install directory. Content added file doesn't works.

I'm trying to save Lua script in text file, and then execute it. I'm using 'Aluminium Lua' library.

```
if (runAtStartup == false)
{
    runAtStartup = true;

    try
    {
        prs = new AluminumLua.LuaParser(ctx, "main.lua");
        prs.Parse();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

This code throws me this exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   Could not find file 'C:\Data\Programs{9B9E8659-C441-4B00-A131-3C540F5CEE4F}\Install\main.lua'.

How to add file to install directory?

Answer (score 2):

Add your files as content to your project.
You can access your Files with:

```
string folder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path;
string path = string.Format(@"{0}\data\myData.bin", folder);
StorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
Stream stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
```

or something like this:

```
string folder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path;
string currentMovieVideoPath = string.Format(@"{0}\media\video\Movie.mp4", folder);
this.MovieVideo.Source = new Uri(currentMovieVideoPath, UriKind.Absolute);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this in some of my phone apps by adding the files as Content to a specific folder within my project tree (e.g. /Data).  Then, when the app runs for the very first time, I copy the content files to isolated storage where my app can then read it as needed.  Here is a simple example:

```
// Check for data files and copy them to isolated storage if they're not there...
// See below for methods found in simple IsolatedStorageHelper class
var isoHelper = new IsolatedStorageHelper();

if (!isoHelper.FileExists("MyDataFile.xml"))
{
    isoHelper.SaveFilesToIsoStore(new[] { "Data\\MyDataFile.xml" }, null);
}

/* IsolatedStorageHelper Methods */

/// <summary>
/// Copies the content files from the application package into Isolated Storage.
/// This is done only once - when the application runs for the first time.
/// </summary>
public void SaveFilesToIsoStore(string[] files)
{
    SaveFilesToIsoStore(files, null);
}

/// <summary>
/// Copies the content files from the application package into Isolated Storage.
/// This is done only once - when the application runs for the first time.
/// </summary>
public void SaveFilesToIsoStore(string[] files, string basePath)
{
    var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    foreach (var path in files)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

        if (basePath != null)
        {
            fileName = Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);
        }

        // Delete the file if it's already there
        if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            isoStore.DeleteFile(fileName);
        }

        var resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));

        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(resourceStream.Stream))
        {
            var data = reader.ReadBytes((int)resourceStream.Stream.Length);

            SaveToIsoStore(fileName, data);
        }
    }
}
```

The downside to this approach is that you essentially have the data files stored twice.  The up side is that they're very easy to work with once they're in isolated storage.  All that said, I don't know what the Lua APIs support - i.e. I don't know if they can load from isolated storage.  If not, you can always open a file stream and possibly load the Lua script file that way.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answer. Could you explain me, where should I put this code, to make it working only at first run of my app?

Comment: PS. I have problem with 'Application' class. It's in System.Windows namespace, which is not availble in Windows Phone SDK 8.0

Comment: In my case, I check for the existence of the file in Isolated Storage before I access it.  If it's not there, I call the above code; otherwise, I just call Isolated Storage as usual.  However, you could also put it in the App.xaml.cs file in the Application_Launching event.  Within the file, check for the existence of the file in Isolated Storage and call the above code if it's not already there.

Comment: P.S. As for the Application class, I am compiling against the 7.1 API but running it on Windows Phone 8 just fine.  I haven't tried compiling it against the 8.0 API as of yet but I would assume there would be something comparable to get a stream.